# Найти все кнопки button на странице через JS и дать класс

Tags: javascript, классы

У меня такая задача, нужно с помощью JS, найти все кнопки из дива .buttons и задать им класс. Никак не могу справляться с этим, я не очень разбираюсь пока что.
Какие варианты решения можете предлагать ?
Спасибо.

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" onclick="">
    <span>В корзину</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

>> [CSS селекторы](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button');

buttons.forEach( button => button.classList.add('red') );
```

```css
.red { color: red; border: 2px solid red; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button> - - - </button>
  <button> - - </button>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button> - - - </button>
</div>
```

Или же,

```
for( let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++ ) {
  buttons[i].classList.add('red');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое